# jax-ws maven plugin sets wsdlLocation to absolute path

Tags: web-services, maven, wsdl, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I generate web service client using

```
<plugin> 
 <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
 <version>2.3</version> 
 <configuration>
  <target>2.1</target> 
  <xnocompile>false</xnocompile> 
 </configuration>
 <executions>
  <execution> 
   <goals> 
    <goal>wsimport</goal> 
   </goals>
  </execution> 
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

my EndpointService.wsdl is in src/main/wsdl. Plugin generates EndointServiceService.java with annotation

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "EndpointServiceService", targetNamespace = "http://soap.endpoint.fsg.ftc/", wsdlLocation = "file:/D:/Source/java/branches/9.3.0/camel-smev/wscapi/src/wsdl/EndpointService.wsdl")
```

so if wsdl

```
D:/Source/java/branches/9.3.0/camel-smev/wscapi/src/wsdl/EndpointService.wsdl
```

not exist(on another machine), it throw exception in runtime.
if i copy wsdl to this dir it runs successfully. How can i include wsdl into my target jar and make client use it? Or how to exclude wsdl dependency at runtime at all? Maybe try older version or another plugin?

Answer (score 4):

add the < wsdllocation > tag in the plugin configuration to a relative path for your wsdl.
you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802487/controlling-jax-ws-wsdllocation-attribute-values-absolute-path-with-jaxws-mav)

Comment: Add an category file in META-INF.